# What causes some herk and jerk while braking?

Tags: brakes, hyundai, brake-rotor, sonata

I'm having some sligt herk and jerk intermittently while braking in my 2010 Hyundai Sonata.

Any ideas on possible causes? Thanks!

Comment: Can you describe what exactly is happening a little better? There's no way to answer what you're asking with any level of accuracy.

Comment: Could you define "*herk and jerk*" for us? That is not a technical term I am familiar with, other than related to some people I used to work with. :-D

Comment: Sure. The braking isn't smooth. It feels like it jerks back and lunges forward, intermittently.

Comment: How do your brakes lunge *forward*? Do you hear a grumbling noise while braking? Does the pedal vibrate and feel like you're walking on gravel (how I describe ABS)? Have you checked your brake pads and rotors? Is your brake fluid low? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With what detail you have given, I will say the typical cause for what you are describing is the brake rotors/drums are no longer true.

To resolve this, a complete brake job must be done on which ever end of the vehicle is having issues. It is far more common for this to be caused by the front rotors than by the rear, but it could be either or both. An inspection will help determine this.

It is also possible it could be something else less common, but I have no way to know from what information you have provided.